# N-package-problems extending from 01 package (from peer grading)

Tags: algorithm

This is a problem I found when I was focusing on peer grading.

The original problem is that I have N students, and N papers. I need to distribute those papers to each of the students and let them grade. Each paper should be graded 5 times, and each students should grade 5 papers. The distribution is based on the "relativity" between the student and the paper, and the distribution should satisfy the highest relativity.

I found this problem relatively similar to 01 package problem, and simplified the problem as following:

`There are N*5 items, and N bags. It is required to put the items into the bags, each bag containing 5 items, while not having same paper. Put the items into the bags, and satisfy the highest cost.`

But the original DP requires an exponential complexity, so is there any algorithm or optimization that can satisfy this requirement?

Comment: It seems that we can only provide approximation for this problem. Let me think for more time.

Comment: You don't state it explicitly, but do you expect a polynomial-time algorithm? It seems so.

Comment: @HaotianLiu did you find the solution for this problem? If yes kindly share it, because i am having the same problem as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this problem can be modeled as a [generalized assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem) where each agent has a budget of `5` and each assignment causes a cost of `1`, which will force to have each agent assigned exactly `5` tasks.